# Yelp: getting documentId for certain operationName

Tags: javascript, websites, development

Going through devtools activity for [this page](https://www.yelp.com/biz/robin-s-snowflake-donuts-and-cafe-spring) (reproducible for any Yelp business page), there's a reference to a `GetReviewSummary` GraphQL operation in a javascript file. This data shows up in the page source within a script tag's JSON near the `reviewCountsByRating` key, after the page fully loads. Rather than have to load the full page every time to obtain this data, it seems smarter to perform the `GetReviewSummary` operation and get that JSON immediately.
These operation names seem to be part of POST requests to `https://www.yelp.com/gql/batch`, which needs a payload looking something like this:

```
import requests

json_data = [
    {
        'operationName': 'GetNotRecommendedReviewsProps', # not necessary, but illustrates the operationName idea
        'variables': {
            'BizEncId': 'GX11hWfQDDqjSEJ-5R0MVQ', # id of the business in question
        },
        'extensions': {
            'documentId': 'e5375d7efbef7d828bab3b1afdd123409a8da596071f5da9e39773d462235b64', # somehow this is derived
        },
    },
]

response = requests.post('https://www.yelp.com/gql/batch', json=json_data)
```

The `documentId` field seems to be set in javascript, but seems difficult to determine how its derived. It's a SHA256 hex digest string and has to be valid (existing?) to produce a successful 200 response. `documentId:  e5375d7efbef7d828bab3b1afdd123409a8da596071f5da9e39773d462235b64` goes with `operationName: GetNotRecommendedReviewsProps`. I've searched for how to get the similar `documentId` for `GetReviewSummary` , but no luck.

It seems since the request is happening from a JS file, there is no corresponding response value to search through for the various network calls. It just shows up in the script section of the HTML once the page is done loading.

Is it possible to see where/when `GetReviewSummary` gets called and its payload?